# How to prevent application from freezing in a long running process?

Tags: delphi

The app seems to freeze sometimes when we try to pass a lot of imported files at once, which is done a each call of the function below for each file so the proposed solution is to add a sleep, but I can't seem to find proper documentation or explaining on how to handle it, or if I can even pass it as a parameter in a function.

This is the call for the proc

```
OpenQuery(FOrderToImportQuery.Database,FOrderToImportQuery);
```

My suggested idea if I can pass Sleep as Param

```
OpenQuery(FOrderToImportQuery.Database,FOrderToImportQuery, Sleep(200));
```

This is the function itself minus the sleep

```
procedure OpenQuery(aDatabase : TIBDatabase; aQuery : TIBQuery);
begin
  if aDatabase.Connected = false  then
    databaseConnect(aDatabase);

  if aDatabase.connected then
  begin
    try
      aQuery.Open;
    except
      //try
        aDatabase.ForceClose;
        aDatabase.Open;
        aQuery.Open;
      {
      except
        on e: exception do
        begin
          Log('Error opening query : '+e.Message);
        end;
      end;
      }
    end;
  end;

end;
```

The idea is I want the call to wait so it can complete properly before being called again. Would it be just fine to put Sleep at the end of the function itself?(Before the last END)

Or would passing it as a parameter in the call of the function be best? And if is so, how is this achieved... I can't find any doc on this particular circumstance.

Comment: calling sleep won't do any good since you are working in the same thread...

Comment: The correct way to make the main thread responsive, is to put all your work in a separate thread. Sleep won't help at all.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think calling Sleep would help.  What are the contents of your `FOrderToImportQuery` parameter when you call your `OpenQuery`?

Comment: Sleep is what I was suggested to use for this problem via a colleague. Unanimously it seems sleep won't do me good, so what would be the proper way to handle this? I should move the call to a separate thread and make the main one sleep while this is running?

Comment: @MartynA It's an SQL query calling a procedure with an ID paramter passed from the file to the proc

Comment: You don't need to call Sleep anywhere. Calling it in the main thread will freeze the GUI for that amount of time. Learn how to put extensive work in a separate thread.

Comment: `Sleep` will make your problem worse, since it will add 200ms of wait (or _freezing_) for each file. And sleeping the main thread while worker thread do all the job is just as bad as letting the main thread do the work itself.

Comment: "calling a procedure with an ID paramter passed from the file to the proc"  Well, if you would show readers exactly what the query is, maybe someone could suggest how to speed it up.  Otherwise. all you are likely to get is guesswork.

Comment: @MartynA I don't think you want to see the 1000+ line of code the proc is handling. I just need to make sure that when that call is made, it completes before it's trying to call it again for the next file. Tho considering the discussion going on about threads, and the fact that I have no separate threads to begin with, this is leading me to think that it's already doing 1:1 calls and not overlapping.

Comment: @Denis, a heavy work done in the main thread will stop the main thread from being responsive. If you put that in a separate thread, the GUI will act normally. If you want to protect the work to be started while another one is started, use btn.enabled= false while the work is progressing and restore the enabled property when done.

Comment: I'm not sure you understand what's going on when you say " I just need to make sure that when that call is made, it completes before it's trying to call it again for the next file."   If you are making your calls to OpenQuery from the same thread, necessarily the first call would complete before you could make the second call (unless you were using asynchronous queries and I'm not sure whether the IB components support async queries).  If the first call to OpenQuery hangs, a subsequent call to it from the same thread will never get called.

Comment: @MartynA I'm not sure where i'm confusing you so i'll re-iterate

The OpenQuery calls a procedure run in SQL, let's pretend it does 1 + 1 every time. I just want that 1 + 1 to finish before the next call. The person who assigned me to correct this because the app was "freezing" (orders not imported) told me to use a Sleep(), so that the calls did not overlap on each other causing the service to freeze. It's becoming apparently clear that I have no threads, all is run from the main, so the call HAS to complete before it runs again, thus there may no overlapping at all to begin. Or am I wrong?

Comment: run query in Async mode. check property `ExecuteOptions`

Comment: @Denis Why did your colleagues believe the problem was with overlapping calls to database? That assumption is what sounds weird here.

Comment: You're not confusing me, thanks.  The mistake you and you co-worker seem to be making is to believe that the calls to "OpenQuery" overlap.  They cannot, if they are called from the same thread.  And even if they were called from different threads, your "log-jam" occurs in the execution of one of them, not by an interaction between distinct calls to OpenQuery.

Comment: Yeah that's the conclusion i'm getting at here. Learned some for sure.The issue stems from elsewhere but there's no more doubt that Sleep will do nothing for me. Thanks for the extensive write ups!

Comment: Not sure why you think Sleep (take a nap) would *prevent from freezing*. Most things stop when they go to sleep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The idea is I want the call to wait so it can complete properly before being called again.

Then the idea of using Sleep() is completely misconceived.

If, in a single thread, you call procedures A, B and C, as in

```
A;
B;
C;
```

then execution in the thread will only ever proceed to `B` **after** the call to `A` returns.  Adding a `Sleep()` in either of them or in between them will only delay things:  if there is a "log-jam" in `A`, adding a call to `Sleep()` in or after it will make no difference whatsoever.  The fact that `A`, `B` and `C` all call your `OpenQuery` makes no difference either.

This is true even if `A` runs an asynchronous query, because the whole point of a call to an asynchronous query is that the call returns before the query completes - an asynchronous query spawns its own background thread in which the query actually executes, then typically passes the results back to the VCL thread via a call to `Synchronize()`.

You have had comments suggesting that you put your query in a separate worker thread (separate from the VCL thread, that is).  That's fine for stopping the VCL thread seizing up while waiting for the query(s) to complete, but including calls to `Sleep()` in the worker thread won't help there either.

So, the *real* answer to your q is for you to investigate and solve why a single call to `OpenQuery` causes the program to hang.  But that's not what you've asked ...

Answer (score 1):

First of all, let me say that I'm assuming your code is as optimized as it can be, and the time it takes to complete is inherently long. If you believe this might not be the case, you should open a new question with the details of your queries so we can help you on this.

### Sleeping your main thread is definitely not the answer

The [Sleep](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/desktop/ms686298(v=vs.85).aspx) function will actually suspend the main thread for the amount of milliseconds specified. So, you will actually just be *freezing* your gui even more than now.

### Worker thread

Creating a worker thread to handle the long-running work is probably your best bet to keep your program responsive while it's doing all the dirty work.

You'll have to take some precautions, though, because you probably don't want the user to be using the program while it's running the worker thread. For example, you don't want the user to click the start button again; or close the application, etc. But if these precautions are something like freezing the main thread, then you better just freeze it with the long-running work, anyway.

Maybe you will want a cancel button somewhere, if this is a process that can be interrupted in the middle (proper control of database transactions could provide this option safely).

Your worker thread could be something along these lines:

```
type
  TWorkerThread = class(TThread)
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FDatabase: TIBDatabase;
    FListQueries: TStringList;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create(aDatabase: TIBDatabase; ListQueries: TStringList; CreateSuspended: Boolean);
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

implementation

{ TWorkerThread }

constructor TWorkerThread.Create(aDatabase: TIBDatabase; ListQueries: TStringList; CreateSuspended: Boolean);
begin
  FListQueries.Create;
  FListQueries.Assign(ListQueries);
  FDatabase := aDatabase;

  inherited Create(CreateSuspended);
end;

destructor TWorkerThread.Destroy;
begin
  FListQueries.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TWorkerThread.Execute;
var i: Integer;
  ibQuery: TIBQuery;
begin
  { Place thread code here }
  ibQuery := TIBQuery.Create(aDatabase);
  try
    for i := 0 to FListQueries.Count - 1 do begin
      if Terminated then
        Exit;

      ibQuery.SQL.Clear;
      ibQuery.SQL.Add(FListQueries[i]);

      OpenQuery(FDatabase, ibQuery);
    end;
  finally
    ibQuery.Free;
  end;
end;
```

PS: I'm sorry if there are compilation errors or if code for TIBDatabase/TIBQuery is wrong, I don't use any of these.

PPS: There is probably a problem with this code, though: I believe that the TIBConnection is very likely to not be thread-safe (I believe the client library itself is not). So you actually should create one connection just for use within the worker thread, rather than just use the same from main thread. I'll leave this correction for you, though. ;)

Comment: I'd appreciate feedback on downvote, btw. That's the whole point on participating in a community: learning.

Comment: Maybe because SO answers are intended primarily for the benefit of future readers, and thread code that's not been tested against the db components involved isn't likely to.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i'll need some time to review it parallel to my project. This is an automated service, no client touches this. It's installed as a service on windows and run at an interval. I'm assuming by now with all the talks on threads that my program actually completes the call before doing the next one, as it is all in the main thread and there are no separate worker threads for this. Am I right in assuming this? (If there are simply no specified threads)

Comment: @MartynA thanks for the feedback, but would you be more specific? Only relevant thing I see is thread safety with TIBConnection, but I like the idea of leaving this as a warning so asker and future readers are encouraged to research and understand implications of code they are using.

Comment: @Denis I'm starting to think I missed the whole point here. If no user ever touches this application, why is it a problem to become unresponsive while it's working? But you are right, as MartynA pointed out in comments to the question, if you are using only one thread, there is no way you can be making simultaneous calls to the database (unless in the unlikely case of async calls, again as pointed out by MartynA). And doing all the worker in a single worker thread would also prevent that, but I don't see why you would need it. Does windows periodically asks for feedbacks from services?

Comment: A depressing number of people who find answers on SO will just cut and paste the code with no thought or attempt to understand.  Some will come back and asking "Why isn't this working?" but others won't and draw their own conclusions about Delphi and/or SO.  That's why personally I only ever post **compilable** and **tested** code in my answers on SO, accompanied when necessary with caveats about its use.  Btw, the point of downvotes on SO answers isn't to snub the answerer but to help the good answers "float to the top" (their wordsm not mine).

Comment: @GabrielF See it's my first programming job since grad in a language I don't know. Hence I am usually directed in a direction via suggestions by seniors, but this project was made by someone who i'm replacing. I think a lack of general knowledge from all parties involved led to this suggestion, and my confusion while researching it. But with your answer + others it's become more clear. There are no threads and the problem must have risen from somewhere else. Calls are definitely not overlapping and slapping a Sleep will just slow the current process down, not singularize it as it is already.

Comment: @Denis yep, problem is probably somewhere else. I have done tons of sequential queries to database (Firebird) and don't remember ever adding sleeps to avoid overlapping (and how would you know how much to sleep in the case that this was needed?). I'm sure my calls are synchronous, though. This answer is not useful for you, sorry.

Comment: @GabrielF all good, if anything that leaves me with a base reference point for the day I will be working with threads. I'll be sure to revisit this post in due time. Thanks!

Comment: @Denis:  Using threads will only move your problem, not solve it.

Comment: @Denis Suddenly mentioning this being "an automated service ... run at an interval" opens a truckload more questions. What kind of service? How frequently is it run? What's the trigger? How did you determine "the app is freezing"? It seems highly likely the problems are being misdiagnosed. I'm no longer even certain whether your service _is_ running the proc 1 at a time serially. You seem unaware of its internals. I suggest you go back to the beginning and diagnose _what is causing the freeze:_ Check for blocked sql processes. Debug your service. Confirm **with certainty** how many threads.

Comment: @CraigYoung Yeah it's a tough cookie, i'm learning the language and i'm not used to working with threads nor debugging(it's really my first job). I don't know how I debug something that is installed as a service, as the GUI is simply for inputting settings e.g FTP location, where to import from, and intervals to scan through the FTP. There's obviously threadtimers in the code but I can't tell that the threads are explicitly called in order rather than just on a interval timer. It's a hard read for something I don't master well. Time to go do my homework I guess